# Why is the inventory not being created?

Tags: laravel

Consider the following models:

```
class Character extends Model {

    // ...

    public function inventory() {
        return $this->hasOne(Inventory::class);
    }
}


class Inventory extends Model {

    // ...

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'id', 'item_id');
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    // ....
}
```

Should be simple to follow: `Character---hasOne-->Inventory--hasMany-->Item`

So you would expect the following to work:

```
$character->inventory()->create([
    'character_id' => $character->id,
    'item_id' => 1,
]);
```

So now when you do: `$character->inventory` you should see we have one item in there.

What I am trying to do, without a many-many table is: A character has one inventory that has many items.

What this above gives me, when we do: `$character->inventory` is `null`. Why?

Comment: ```dd($character->inventory()->create([
    'character_id' => $character->id,
    'item_id' => 1,
]);)```, and see what returns

Comment: @TheWebs can post where is the inital value of $character

Comment: You do not need to pass the key of the parent model, eloquent will take care of that, just pass the other fields. But note that it will not be the Inventory model that will keep the Item key, but it should be the Item that keeps its owner's key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A character has one inventory that has many items.

So the relationships should be

```
class Character extends Model {

    public function inventory() {
        // there should be an 'character_id' field on Inventory model.
        return $this->hasOne(Inventory::class);
    }
}


class Inventory extends Model {

    public function items() {
        // there should be an 'inventory_id' field on Item model.
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    public function inventory() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Inventory::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can create the relate Inventory like this:

```
$inventory = Character::find(1)->inventory()->create([
    'name' => 'Inventory 1',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getting null in $character->inventory() because you didn't specify in which owner key you'll be using.

This the sample create method in Laravel Docs

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$comment = $post->comments()->create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```

Have a look to this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)